# Mobile version of symfony app - partials

Tags: mobile, symfony1, partials

I want to make sth like this

[Mobile version of my Symfony project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500488/mobile-version-of-my-symfony-project/5506791)

when file xxxSuccess.mobile.php does not exist, it should load xxxSuccess.php. It works OK. But it doesn't work with partials. I want to load _partialfilename.mobile.php but if it doesn't exist it should load _partialfilename.php. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own `PartialView` class from `sfPartialView` and change the `render()` method in a similar way like you did with the template.
You can do it per module, with [module.yml](http://www.symfonyreference.com/module-yml). Have a look at the `get_partial` function in PartialHelper.php to see how it works. Same thing for components, if you need it in the future .